# Accessing a file in perl

Tags: perl

In my script I am dealing with opening files and writing to files.  I found that there is  some thing wrong with a file I try to open, the file exists, it is not empty and I am passing the right path to file handle.

I know that my question might sounds weird but while I was debugging my code I put the following command in my script to check some files

```
system ("ls");
```

Then my script worked well, when it's removed it does not work correctly anymore.

```
 my @unique = ("test1","test2");
 open(unique_fh,">orfs");
 print unique_fh @unique ;
 open(ORF,"orfs")or die ("file doesnot exist");
 system ("ls");
    while(<ORF>){
    split ;
    }
    @neworfs=@_ ;
  print @neworfs ;
```

Comment: Can you provide a short example, including a `system("ls")` which fails when that line is commented out?

Comment: Also try "use strict;" and see if there are any warnings.

Comment: `use strict;` **and** `use warnings;`. Also show us the code that you are using to try to open the file handle (and what code you have to test if it succeeded).

Comment: And `something wrong` is... ?

Comment: I have updated the question ,if you comment system ("ls") it wont work !!!

Comment: I'm *guessing* that the problem is because you are trying to work with two file handles on one file. You might want to look at [IPC::Open2](https://metacpan.org/module/IPC::Open2)

Comment: I am curious as to why you think @_ contains anything, and what you think split will do. Why not just do `@neworfs = map split, <ORF>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not close the filehandle before trying to read from the same file.

Comment: This answer may solve the problem, but its lack of explanation makes it a poor answer.

Answer (score 5):

Perl buffers the output when you print to a file.  In other words, it doesn't actually write to the file every time you say `print`; it saves up a bunch of data and writes it all at once.  This is faster.

In your case, you couldn't see anything you had written to the file, because Perl hadn't written anything yet.  Adding the `system("ls")` call, however, caused Perl to write your output first (the interpreter is smart enough to do this, because it thinks you might want to use the `system()` call to do something with the file you just created).

How do you get around this?  You can close the file before you open it again to read it, as choroba suggested.  Or you can disable buffering for that file.  Put this code just after you open the file:

```
my $fh = select (unique_fh);
$|=1;
select ($fh);
```

Then anytime you print to the file, it will get written immediately (`$|` is a special variable that sets the output buffering behavior).

Closing the file first is probably a better idea, although it is possible to have a filehandle for reading and writing open at the same time.